# Build failure with osx

Tags: c, macos

My code builds with Linux and OpenBSD. Now I want it to build with osx but I get this error from travis-ci that I don't fully understand.

```
^

In file included from edit.c:1:

./sh.h:436:8: error: expected ')'

/usr/include/secure/_string.h:105:44: note: expanded from macro 'strlcpy'

  __builtin___strlcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz (dest))

                                           ^

/usr/include/secure/_common.h:39:62: note: expanded from macro '__darwin_obsz'

#define __darwin_obsz(object) __builtin_object_size (object, _USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL > 1 ? 1 : 0)

                                                             ^

/usr/include/secure/_common.h:30:32: note: expanded from macro '_USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL'

#    define _USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL 2

                               ^

./sh.h:436:8: note: to match this '('

/usr/include/secure/_string.h:105:44: note: expanded from macro 'strlcpy'

  __builtin___strlcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz (dest))

                                           ^

/usr/include/secure/_common.h:39:53: note: expanded from macro '__darwin_obsz'

#define __darwin_obsz(object) __builtin_object_size (object, _USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL > 1 ? 1 : 0)

                                                    ^

In file included from edit.c:1:

./sh.h:436:8: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]

size_t strlcpy(char *, const char *, size_t);

       ^

/usr/include/secure/_string.h:105:44: note: expanded from macro 'strlcpy'

  __builtin___strlcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz (dest))

                                           ^

/usr/include/secure/_common.h:39:31: note: expanded from macro '__darwin_obsz'

#define __darwin_obsz(object) __builtin_object_size (object, _USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL > 1 ? 1 : 0)

                              ^

In file included from edit.c:1:

./sh.h:436:8: error: conflicting types for '__builtin___strlcpy_chk'

/usr/include/secure/_string.h:105:3: note: expanded from macro 'strlcpy'

  __builtin___strlcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz (dest))

  ^

./sh.h:436:8: note: '__builtin___strlcpy_chk' is a builtin with type 'unsigned long (char *, const char *, unsigned long, unsigned long)'

/usr/include/secure/_string.h:105:3: note: expanded from macro 'strlcpy'

  __builtin___strlcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz (dest))
```

My macro is

```
#ifndef strlcpy
/* Linux has no concept of strlcpy(). */
#define strlcpy(x, y, z) snprintf((x), (z), "%s", (y))
#endif
```

I understand that osx and OpenBSD have `strlcpy` but I don't know how to handle it.

What can I do about it?

Comment: You can't use `#ifndef` to test whether a function has been declared, if that's what you're attempting. You need conditions on the platform.

Comment: You already know about the concept of *conditional compilation* (that's what's the `#ifndef/#endif` thing is). Use it to detect the platform (the compiler will define special macros that are platform specific).

Comment: And depending on how you configure and build your application, if you have some kind of configure-script or similar then you it should have some functionality to check for existence of functions. Add such a check, and if it exists then set a special macro that you then check for in the source.

Comment: You may want to use an automatic configuration tool such as [GNU autotools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Build_System)

Comment: Please create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  What you've shown is sub-minimal — not enough code.  It's a nuisance to have to work out code that reproduces the problem.  I tried; I failed.  That's a nuisance.

Comment: I'm not sure about modern C compilers, but in the past, the opening paren `(` for a macro invocation must be immediately after the macro name, no spaces between  Also suggest placing parens around `_USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL > 1 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
#include <string.h>

#ifndef strlcpy
/* Linux has no concept of strlcpy(). */
#define strlcpy(x, y, z) snprintf((x), (z), "%s", (y))
#endif

int main() {
  char a[1];
  char b[1];
  strlcpy(a, b, 1);
  return 0;
}
```

compiles just fine on macOS. I know that Travis-CI recently disabled support for older XCode versions. Maybe this is the issue?